# Looking for alternatives to mcrypt for PHP server using 'Twofish' encryption

Tags: php

At my workplace, our server is still running on an older PHP 5.6 but our host will soon stop supporting this version and we'll be upgrading to 7.x. Some of the data going through it gets encrypted/decrypted using the 'Twofish' algorithm into/out of our database.

The problem? My predecessor who wrote the script that handles the encryption was using the old 'dl()' command and relying the the 'mcrypt' library, which from my understanding via google searches are both no longer supported in newer PHP versions.

Since we're now too far in with lots of SQL tables already containing encrypted data, I'm looking for alternative ways to apply the 'Twofish' algorithm. What are some alternative options I can make use of going forward? Any libraries/sources I can rely on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick lookup for `Twofish` at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) will return the [phpseclib](https://packagist.org/packages/phpseclib/phpseclib) package which requires **PHP >= 5.6.1** and it has the `phpseclib3/Crypt/Twofish` class which you can use to encrypt/decrypt data like this:

```php
use phpseclib3\Crypt\Twofish;

$tf = new Twofish('cbc');
$tf->setIV(str_repeat("\0", $tf->getBlockLength() >> 3));

// key size = 128
$key = pack('H*', '00000000000000000000000000000000');
$tf->setKey($key);

$ciphertext = $tf->encrypt('Encrypted text!');
echo $tf->decrypt($ciphertext); // Encrypted text!
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this Packagist website, thank you!

Comment: @AvivKomemi if my anwser helped you solve the problem, then please mark it as accepted answer. This way, you will help future developers having similar issues with you, to resolve their problems.